# I have these controllers that deletes a user, i want to implement DRY(Don't repeat yourself) principle and make the res json message dynamic

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to implement a DRY principle for my code below which deletes two different user and also i want to implement a dynamic response based on the details of the model provided to the find method

```
//This code here deletes the student
exports.deleteStudent = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let ID = req.query.id
        let exactStudent = await Student.findById(ID)
        if (!exactStudent) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Student with the specified ID not present" })
        }
        await Student.findByIdAndDelete(ID);
        res.status(200).json({ success: 'Student Deleted successfully ' })
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

//the code here deletes the teachers

```
exports.deleteTeacher = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let ID = req.query.id
        let exactTeacher = await Teacher.findById(ID)
        if (!exactTeacher) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Teacher with the specified ID not present" })
        }
        await Teacher.findByIdAndDelete(ID);
        res.status(200).json({ error: 'Teacher Deleted successfully ' })
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have two database calls for find and then delete. The delete operation returns the deleted document when matched - and null when there is no match.

Comment: Thanks, but i still have to write the findanddelete metho each time i want to delete, i want to make it clean and DRY as much as possible

Comment: Clean code would involve that the  (1) database operations be in another module., (2) catch and throw error in a route handler method - is not acceptable. The user of the API need to know something; like a status 500 response.

Comment: Thanks code rectified

Comment: When you have all the code - the validation, error (database and application) handling, security, etc., related code in your application - then you will be able to write a very modular and reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, you need something like this:

```
async function deletePerson(Model, id) => {
    try {
        return await Model.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

// Inside the controllers

exports.deleteStudent = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const deletedEntity = await deletePerson(Student, req.query.id);
        if (!deletedEntity) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Student with the specified ID not present" })
        }
        res.status(200).json({ error: 'Student Deleted successfully ' })
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}

exports.deleteTeacher = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const deletedEntity = await deletePerson(Teacher, req.query.id);
        if (!deletedEntity) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Teacher with the specified ID not present" })
        }
        res.status(200).json({ error: 'Teacher Deleted successfully ' })
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot i rectified the code